# Differentiation/ find the derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Can anybody please help me with my work?
I have to find the differentiate/ find the derivative of these two question:
Please HELP!!!

1. $sin^2(cos3x^3)^5 $
2. $cot^2(x)((x^2)(3cos^3(3x)))^2$

Comment: Chain rule chain rule chain rule chain rule

Comment: i tried but i cannot get to the answer

Comment: Why would a teacher assign such a ridiculous question?

Comment: without proper parentheses, it is difficult to tell what is wanted, especially in the first question.

Comment: I would propose to check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+sin%5E2%28cos%283*x%5E3%29%5E5) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+cot%28x%29%5E2%28%28x%5E2%29%283*cos%5E3%283*x%29%29%29%5E2). You can create a free trial account to see the proof...

Comment: thanks moray95 that helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain rule

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2(\cos3x^3)^5&=2\sin(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\cos3x^3)^5\\
&=2\sin(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot\cos(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\cos3x^3)^5\\
&=2\sin(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot\cos(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot5(\cos3x^3)^4\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\cos3x^3\\
&=who\ the\ hell\ made\ you\ do\ this
\end{align}$$

Comment: Run out of breath ? = $-2\sin(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot\cos(\cos3x^3)^5\cdot5(\cos3x^3)^4\cdot 9x^2\cdot\sin3x^3\\$

Comment: The second question is the most difficult.